# Click event is not raised for Button in popup on datagrid

Tags: wpf, events, popup, click, itemtemplate

I'am quite new with WPF and still trying to figure it out in all its details ;)
I have a strange issue with the button not raising its click event. I have a UserControl called PopupButton which is basically a button with a popup showed on click. The content of the popup is ContentPresenter and is binded to the dependency property called PopupContentHolder on the PopupButton.
Then on the main form I have a DataGrid with DataGridTemplateColumn where in the  `<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate> <DataTemplate>` I placed my PopupButton. Then I assign a list box with an ItemTemplate as the content of the popup for my PopupButton.
In simple this looks as follows

```
<DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
        ColumnHeaderHeight="40"
        FontSize="11"
        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Pocos}"
        RowHeight="30"
        SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn MinWidth="70" Header="NAme">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <controls:PopupButton DoPopupOnMainButton="True"
                                        Foreground="{StaticResource HeaderLinkActiveColor}"
                                        MarkButtonOnPopup="True"
                                        PopupBackground="{StaticResource PopupBackground}"
                                        PopupPadding="5"
                                        ShowDownArrow="False"
                                        Text="Some test button">
                    <controls:PopupButton.PopupContentHolder>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <ListBox Background="Transparent" ItemsSource="{Binding Tenders}">
                                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Button Margin="0,2,0,0"
                                                Click="Button_Click"
                                                Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}},
                                                                    Path=DataContext.SaveCommand}"
                                                Content="{Binding .}"
                                                FontSize="11" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            </ListBox>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </controls:PopupButton.PopupContentHolder>
                </controls:PopupButton>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Now the problem is with the button inside the ListBox in PopupButton, Neither Click event nor Command is raised. Moreover when I put the PopupButton outside the DataGrid then everythinkg works perfect. Also when I put above list box directly in grid cell then it works.
Maybe its something wrong with my PopupButtonControl.

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.PopupButton"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         x:Name="userControlRoot"
         Width="Auto"
         Height="Auto">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis" />

    <Storyboard x:Key="PopupCloseStoryBoard">
        <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="popup" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen">
            <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="False" />
        </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>

    <Storyboard x:Key="PopupOpenStoryBoard">
        <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="popup" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen">
            <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="True" />
        </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>


</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>

    <Border x:Name="brdButtonBack"
            Background="Transparent"
            CornerRadius="3,3,0,0"
            Padding="{Binding Padding,
                              ElementName=userControlRoot}" />

    <Button x:Name="btnMain"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Click="btn_Click"
            Command="{Binding MainCommand,
                              ElementName=userControlRoot}"
            Content="{Binding Text,
                              ElementName=userControlRoot}"
            IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled,
                                ElementName=userControlRoot}" />

    <Popup x:Name="popup"
           MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth,
                              ElementName=userControlRoot}"
           AllowsTransparency="True"
           Placement="Bottom"
           PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=brdButtonBack}"
           PopupAnimation="Slide"
           StaysOpen="False">
        <Border Background="{Binding PopupBackground,
                                     ElementName=userControlRoot}"
                BorderBrush="White"
                CornerRadius="0,3,3,3"
                Padding="{Binding PopupPadding,
                                  ElementName=userControlRoot}">

            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding PopupContentHolder, ElementName=userControlRoot}" />
        </Border>
    </Popup>

</Grid>
```

I have simplified the control but the problem reproduces with that version too. The code behind for the control mostly contains  dependency properties, the only logic is shown below

```
public partial class PopupButton : UserControl
{
    //... dependency properties

    public PopupButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            Storyboard s = (Storyboard)TryFindResource("PopupOpenStoryBoard");
            s.Begin();
    }

    private void popup_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        //trick to close popup when the button inside is clicked
        //this must be done with storyboard and delay
        //since popup can not be closed before the event reaches clicked
        //button
        if (e.Source is Button)
        {
            Storyboard s = (Storyboard)TryFindResource("PopupCloseStoryBoard");
            s.Begin();
        }
    }
}
```

Has anyone any clue what can be wrong with it?
Thanks.

Comment: If it's a problem with your UserControl you should post the code for your UserControl too.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've added the xaml and code behind for the UserControl.

Comment: I would appreciate if any one could help with my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did finally solve this by rewriting PopupButton as CustomControl. There, instead of firing StoryBoard to close the popup, when the contained button is clicked I used following code

```
mainPopup.AddHandler(Button.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(mainPopup_ButtonClick), true);
```

Adding a button click handler for main popup, which will be called on the popup even if the event is already handled by the source button.

```
    void mainPopup_ButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainPopup.IsOpen = false;
    }
```

More info about handling already handled routed events [here](http://www.eidias.com/Blog/2013/11/21/handling-already-handled-events-in-wpf)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is just a typo because there is a btn_Click and Button_Click event handler in your code.
Would you mind providing the code of the PopupContentHolder or maybe the whole PopupButton class?